# wp echo the_author_link(); fail to author.php

Tags: wordpress

I wrote the code `<?php echo the_author_link(); ?>` on **theme/xtocky/woocommerce/centent-product.php**

It output the link like `<a href="www.dermaroller.com">zac1987</a>`.

How to make it output the link like `<a href="author.php">zac1987</a>`?

I have created author.php file on both xtocky folder and woocommerce folder, I thought `<?php echo the_author_link(); ?>` will automatic create link to author.php but why it doesn't?

Comment: From the top of my head: all `the_` functions already contain echo inside, all `get_the_` functions return value. So, in your code you may try `echo get_the_author_link();` or just `the_author_link()` without echo.

Comment: Yes u are right, but still didn't fix the problem. I tried your both ways also fail redirect to author.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the correct answer is replace `the_author_link();` with `the_author_posts_link();`

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, just replace my code with `<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a>`

Don't know why cannot use `the_author_link();`. Maybe any expert can explain in future.

Comment: Sorry this is not the answer, this is just redirect to custom author profile php file in the plugin folder.